# How to capture stream data? C# I/O Basic

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to use a  method which accepts two arguments Model type and Stream Type.

```
public static void Write(Stream stream, Model model);
```

Firstly i want to create a variable of type stream and then capture what ever is written to the stream in a string and then store in database. I find that Stream class is a abstract class not sure how to override it.

Can any one please suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some of the derived classes such as [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx):

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // pass the memory stream to the method which will write to it
    SomeClass.Write(stream, someModel);

    // convert the contents to string using the default encoding
    string result = Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());

    // TODO: do something with the result
}
```